# Incrementing to next year when user clicks next arrow in primefaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to naviagate to next year when user clicks the next arrow button in calendar. I am trying to achieve something like this.
[sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk6En.png)
The double arrow would Increment the year value to next year. Though Naviagator is one Option in primefaces, I need a way with keys inside the widget something like the richfaces calendar. So I am trying to override the  event when user clicks next arrow in calendar, **basically I am trying to increment year also along with the month which is done by primefaces**

I tried out the Following with jquery:It is correctly getting the alert whenever user clicks the button, but I am not getting any Idea how the year In the widget can be incremented. How this Should be approached? where should I start? Any references or links is highly helpful.Thanks in advance

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', function () {
          alert('User clicked Next');
          //To do functionality
        });
```

Comment: The PF source is open... And in it is the datapicker source... Way easier to normally override things than to stack hacking with adding additional handlers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using a combination of the PrimeFaces widget and JavaScript Date's setFullYear() method do the following:

Step 1. Navigate to the PF Calendar Showcase Page: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml

Step 2. Press F12 in Chrome to bring up the Javascript Console.

Step 3. Enter the following code in the console and press ENTER you will see the inline calendar change from 2019 to 2020 to 2021 etc.

```
var widget = PrimeFaces.widgets.widget_form_inline;
var nextYear = widget.getDate();
nextYear.setFullYear(nextYear.getFullYear() + 1);
widget.setDate(nextYear);
```

Now if you want to make it generic simply write this JS method and pass the widgetVar from each calendar to it.

```
function incrementYear(widget) {
   var nextYear = widget.getDate();
   if (nextYear) {
      nextYear.setFullYear(nextYear.getFullYear() + 1);
      widget.setDate(nextYear);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton melloware :) It helped me alot in getting to know things. Your Code works like magic. Can you please share some of your insights in the following scenrios ? 1. Initially If the date field is empty the script throws a null pointer exception stating it is not able to find property of null, How this could be handled? It works faboulously for user selecting some year and clicking on the navigator  though. 2 If more than one calendar is present in the same form then how this solution can be tuned to fit all ? Please provide some insights,I am very thankful for your help and Guidance :)

Comment: Updated my answer to add a generic solution where pass the widgetVar in.  So if you have 2 calendars each has a unique widgetVar.  And I do a Null check on the getDate().

Comment: Thanks a ton again melloware :) It works like charm, But Out of curiosity and to learn more I want to explore if the same solution is feasible without actually setting the date in the widget, basically by moving the navigator to another year by javascript. I am not sure whether this can be asked as a comment or need to be asked as a separate question please mention in it in that case. And a million appreciations for the help you have done in to learn more :)

Comment: Oh do you mean there is no date in the widget so its NULL.  And if you press your button you want it to add 1 year?  But add to what make it Jan-01-2020 or to make it 1 year from right now so Feb 12, 2020 ??  Also yes, ask in another Stack Overflow question and I will try an answer it there.

Comment: hi melloware, Thanks for your response. I have asked one question regarding this:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54644463/3729090?sem=2 . Please do share your insights. Actually I want to do it this way, like regardless of what year user clicked or not (like if there is null value also). the year in the widget should move to next year when next arrow is clicked without setting the widget to year , like trying to simulate the navigator behaviour with the help of keys pressed. Please do share your insights on this. Thanks again for responding :)